# Split multi-lines into different array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

since there is a csv file, it is already loaded,but there are 400 lines. how to split different lines into different string array

```
String[] row= data[0][i].split(",") ;
```

> sth,sth,sth,sth,sth,sth sth,sth,sth,sth,sth,sth ....

Comment: Are yo trying to slit at commas or are there new line characters, '\n' in the file where a line should be delimited?

Comment: which language/platform are you talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the solution in java.

If you already loaded the csv file into a string, then use `str.split("\n")` should split the csv file into lines.

If you have an external file to be loaded, then you can use the below code for splitting

```
//use try catch for this
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("csvfile.csv")));
String data = "";

while((data = br.readLine()) != null)
{
      //use an array to capture the output from split()
     data.split("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest you really use a CSV library to parse the lines/file like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

From the looks of the small amount of code you have posted, you have already read in the lines of the csv file into your 2D array `data` where `i` is the index to each line.

If this is the case I suggest that you store your split array of each line into a List of String arrays like so

```
 List<String[]> splitLines = new ArrayList<String[]>();
 for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
 {
      splitLines.add(data[0][i].split(","));
 }
```

Then each array in the list is an array of the lines split by commas